# PHP- Refine search with quotation marks

Tags: php

I get queries which i search in my database by using LIKE statement in sql replacing space with %.

```
$in= str_replace(' ','%',$in);
example : 'harry potter is a great book' becomes 'harry%potter%is%a%great%book'
```

Now i want to refine my search by allowing users to use quotation marks like google does so that

```
' "harry potter" is a great book' become 'harry potter%is%a%great%book'
```

i want to skip those spaces which is inside quotation marks, also the query can contain more than one pair of quotation marks.

```
' "harry potter" is a "great book"' become 'harry potter%is%a%great book'
```

Comment: what if the quotation marks don't match? example `' "harry potter" is a great" book'`. do you want `"harry potter"` or `"harry potter" is a great"` or `" is a great"`?

Comment: Full text searches is what you want, not wildcard searching.

Comment: @mistermartin just `"harry potter"` and also the query can contain more than one pair of quotation marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one quick and dirty way to do it:

```
$str = '"harry potter" is a "great book"';

// get all matches between quotes
preg_match_all('/".*?"/', $str, $matches);

// do your normal replacement, and remove quotes
$str = str_replace(' ', '%', $str);
$str = str_replace('"', '', $str);

// undo quoted replacements
foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
    $value = trim($value, '"');
    $str = str_replace(str_replace(' ', '%', $value), $value, $str);
}

echo $str;
```

This will out:

```
harry potter%is%a%great book
```

However, this is far from perfect. For example, if the same phrase appears more than once, both quoted and un-quoted, then it won't give you the results you'd expect. There are other ways you can handle this but it just adds further complexity.

As Devon mentioned in the comments, you should probably look into using a [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: i want the output as `harry potter%is%a%great book` without quotation marks